# my angular project don't came with some files

Tags: angular

i am currently learning angular (i am a begginer) and my project keep building missing some files like environments.ts, app.module.ts and i really don't know why.
i have tried to create a new project three times already and the same thing happens.
how do i correct this?

[scrrenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzTqr.png)

i expect to my project looks like this

[what i expect for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNVHP.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please use words rather than (or in addition to) images.

Comment: oh sorry! i'm new here and don't really know how to post.

Comment: Also please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]. There's really not much to go on, right now.

Comment: Standalone is future if you need module type project. use this command `ng new my-app --no-standalone --routing --ssr=false`